# auto_ts: How to change forecasted date range in auto_ts

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, sarimax, prophet

I am trying to forecast values using **auto_ts** library, the input i am passing is a date format which has first date of every month like **2021-11-01** whereas the forecasted values have a date range as last date of every month like **2021-11-30**.

Is there a way to change the date range of predicted values to first date of every month?

Comment: Most likely you have to use the `time_interval` parameter and set it to `MS` which means "Month Start"

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are seeing is because autots uses the `pandas` dataframe to infer the frequency.

```
model = AutoTS(
    forecast_length=21,
    frequency='infer',
    prediction_interval=0.9,
    ensemble=None,
    model_list="fast",  # "superfast", "default", "fast_parallel"
    transformer_list="fast",  # "superfast",
    drop_most_recent=1,
    max_generations=4,
    num_validations=2,
    validation_method="backwards"
)
```

`pandas` by default does end-of-month for its monthly spacing. To get start of month, you can use `frequency ='MS'` to get start-of-month:

```
model = AutoTS(
    forecast_length=21,
    frequency='MS', # this is the change needed
    ...)
```